# Dynamic Bash Script (i.e top)

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm wondering if there is a method to have a bash script present data to the console and consistently update it.  Much like the functionality of top, but in a more simple form.

Answer (score 9):

```
watch -n 1 <your-command>
```

From the [watch(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) man page:

> Execute a program periodically, showing output full screen

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about watch.  This is doing exactly what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use curses for this. Here's one detailed article about [curses usage](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-shellcurses/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "while true / clear"-loops to have constantly updated screen like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
clear
echo "your output"
uptime
sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [terminal escape codes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php).  You can print them with `echo -ne` (drop the `n` if you want the newline afterwards).  The escape character is `\033`. This will clear the screen and put your cursor at the top left:

```
echo -ne "\033[2J\033[f"
```

There are cursor-positioning codes, color codes, formatting, etc.